# Change Mavericks Finder column display width in list view?

Tags: finder

I upgraded from SL to Mavericks a month a go and a few things are odd. One is that Finder shows the name column in list view as being wider than my monitor. I guess it's auto-fitting to long URLs. but it is driving me nuts. I would rather have truncated file names and widen the column as required than open a dialogue window and have to scroll right to be able to see the modified column every time...
Is it possible to set a maximum column width?

Answer (score 0):

At the top of the Finder window [in List View] you'll see where the columns for Name, Date etc are. Between each is a grey vertical line. Hover the cursor over the line until it changes to a 2-way arrow, then click & drag to the desired width.
It should then be remembered.

Column view makes up its own mind every time, you can't make it stick. Double-clicking the || at the bottom of any column will auto-expand to the optimum width to read all the file names, but there's no way to make it remember that.

***Edit:***
Column view can be set to remember widths if you hold Opt [alt] whilst dragging the width of one column.